# Login page with mysql select where statment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple login page, on the top simple form validations with if and elseif statments.
I want to write the mysql select where statement below the validation code as an (elseif) statment. if the email and password = the email and password on the database table record, then it will redirect the use to the secured page, and the final (else) will show an error if the email or password don't exist or match in the database.

I really don't know how to do this the right way, this is my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
    <?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php

$email = $_POST['Email'];
$hashed_password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

        if ($_POST['Email'] == "") {    
            $error = "Email address is required";
        }
        elseif (!(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
            $error = "Invalid email address";
        }
        elseif ($_POST['password'] == "") {
            $error = "Type in your password";
        }
        elseif (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {
            $error = "Minimum password length is 8";
        }
        elseif {
            $query = "SELECT id, email ";
            $query .= "FROM customers ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            redirect_to("account.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
        }

    }       
?>
    <!-- signup box -->
    <div id="box_sign">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12 box_wrapper">
                <div class="span12 box">
                    <div>
                        <div class="head">
                            <h4>Sign In</h4><br />
                             <div class="text-error">
                              <?php echo $error; ?><br />
                              <p class="text-success"><strong><?php echo $success; ?></strong></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form">
                            <form action="sign-in.php" method="POST">

                              <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"/>

                              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                                    <div class="right">
                                        <a href="reset.html">Forgot password?</a>
                                    </div>
                              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="already">Don't have an account? 
                    <a href="signin.html">Sign up</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: redirect_to() function i have it in the functions.php file and its working.

Comment: `It doesn't work?` what isn't working? You will have to be a little more specific.

Comment: Your final `elseif` doesn't have a condition. You need to check the MySQL result set to see if it returned a result. If it did, then redirect.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and can't see an example.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

`redirect_to()` is not a pre-defined PHP function, it's a custom function and probably you've picked this code from somewhere else and you forgot to pick up the function code.. It should be probably this

```
function redirect_to($link) {
   header('Location: '.$link);
   exit;
}
```

Also `elseif {` is not valid, it won't work without a condition

Comment: I have the redirect_to($link) function code and it is defined in another page and included in the sign in page on the top. my problem is with the elseif, what is the best way to write it if elseif is not working? and how can i show an error if the email and password don't much the one i have in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
elseif {
    $query = "SELECT id, email ";
    $query .= "FROM customers ";
    $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
    $query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query);
    redirect_to("account.php");
}
```

To:

```
else {
    $query = "SELECT id, email ";
    $query .= "FROM customers ";
    $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
    $query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows()>0){
        Header("Location:account.php");
    }
    else {
        echo 'Password or email is wrong';
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Header(...)` actually work, or should it be `header(...)`?

Comment: why `mysql_affected_rows` and not `mysql_num_rows`?  Or, same difference in this case?